# Using Jinja to loop through a DB table getting error: 'DB name' is undefined

Tags: python, loops, flask, jinja2

Been working on creating a web app using flask. Was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI&t=5286s

My app is a banking app unlike in the video. At this point in my project I am past the video and am trying to create a page where users can view bank accounts that were created by them after they have been stored in the DB.

Using Jinja I tried a for loop to get the accounts associated to a specific user. In the video the guys uses a very similar for loop

```
{% block content %} <div class="container py-3 p-3 my-3 border">
<h3 style="text-align:Center">Your Accounts</h3>
<form name="banks">
    {% for bank in account.bank_accounts %}
    <label for="banks">Choose an Account</label>
    <select id="banks" name="banks">
        <option> value='{{ x }}'>{{x}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Accounts">Account Number:</label>
    </div>
</form></div>{% endblock %}
```

However I keep encountering the error "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'account' is undefined"

Here is my models.py for my bank table and account tables

```
class Bank(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.column(db.String(150))
    number = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    ownership = db.Column(db.String(150))
    type = db.Column(db.String(150))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id'))

class Account(db.Model, UserMixin): #User object, inherit db from models.py, creating a schema
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    bank_accounts = db.relationship('Bank')
```

I have no idea where to start frankly, I am pretty new to making web apps and never used flask before this project. To me it seems that account is defined in the same manner as is set up in the video.

Any help with solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Edit: Here is my views.py which contains the route.

```
@views.route('/accounts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def accounts():
    return render_template("accounts.html", user=current_user)
```

Does account need to be defined in the route? If so I have tried that but I wasn't able to use the select() method. It gave me this error: AttributeError: type object 'Bank' has no attribute 'select'

```
account = Bank.select(account_id)
```

Comment: Can you please add your code for the route to your question. If account is not known in the jinja template, it is interesting to know how the variable is queried and passed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `User` account is actually an `Account` object. If that is indeed the case you can use `current_user.bank_accounts` in your jinja2 template.

```
{% block content %} <div class="container py-3 p-3 my-3 border">
<h3 style="text-align:Center">Your Accounts</h3>
<form name="banks">
        <label for="banks">Choose an Account</label>
        <select id="banks" name="banks">
        {% for bank in current_user.bank_accounts %}
            <option value='{{ bank.name }}'>{{ bank.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Accounts">Account Number:</label>
    </div>
</form></div>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to have resolved that error however, I am not able to populate the options with the for loop.  The loop only contains the <option> tags now. Any way to populate it using a for loop like this?

Comment: What is `x` supposed to be?

Comment: x is supposed to be the names of the banks accounts that the user created. However even trying to pass plain text as an example through the <options> tags doesn't work.

Comment: change `{{ x }}` to `{{ bank.name }}`

Comment: also looks like your `{% endfor %}` is in the wrong location. Probably belongs after the closing `</select>`

Comment: Whatever elements I put in the loop stop working. The <select> tags or the <options> tag. Incidentally I noticed my foreign key for Bank is not being populated in the DB.

Comment: I made an edit to the answer. I had to assume what you are trying to do. Let me know if that gives you what you wanted.

Comment: Can't move this to chat not enough rep...but no this did not work, the drop down is still un populated. There are accounts that I can see in the db that is should loop through.

Comment: This has moved beyond your original question. Probably best to do some debugging and if you're still stuck, ask another question about the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have passed the currently used account as "user" to the template. So "account" is unknown within your template.
With the following code, the current user should be usable as "account" within your template.

```
@views.route('/accounts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def accounts():
    return render_template("accounts.html", account=current_user)
```

But you can also use the `current_user` within your template. This is an exceptional case and takes place via the [global namespace of the jinja environment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#the-global-namespace). @noslenkwah has shown this with an example.

However, you use another variable "x" within your template, which was also not defined. It cannot be overlooked here what you intend to do there. I'm assuming that you want to use an attribute of the "bank" object, but I'm not sure.

Since you have defined a relationship, you do not necessarily need a query through select. The objects of the type "Bank" belonging to the "Account" can be queried via this. As you have already done within the loop. The select query takes place in the background.
You can find the documentation on database relationships [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html).

Should you nevertheless want to query all objects of the type "Bank" from the database, which are assigned to an "Account", you can do this in the following way.

```
bank_accounts = Bank.query.filter_by(account_id=current_user.id).all()
```

You can find an explanation of the basic database queries [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/).

---

To make sure that the current user also has an account, I recommend the following code for the template.

```
{% block content %} 
  <div class="container py-3 p-3 my-3 border">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">Your Accounts</h3>
    {% if current_user.bank_accounts %}
    <form name="banks-form">
      <label for="bank">Choose an Account</label>
      <select id="bank" name="bank">
      {% for bank in current_user.bank_accounts %}
        <option value="{{ bank.id }}">{{ bank.name }} - {{ bank.number }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </form>
    {% else %}
      <p>You have not yet created any accounts.</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Regarding referencing "x". Yes there I intend to display the number attribute for the bank accounts for the current_user. How would this be done?

Comment: @Nicholas Noslenkwah's code should give you the corresponding result. I can only explain to myself that the bank accounts are not assigned to the account. The query is therefore empty.

Comment: @Nicholas I edited my question. I still don't know what exactly you intend to do. I can try to fix the problem with you.